# Mock lombok slf4j

Tags: java, mockito

I want to test the following class

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InvoiceUpdateListener {

@SneakyThrows
  public void receiveInvoice(@NotificationMessage String message) {
    
    var orderNumber = extractOrderNumber(message);
    var order = orderService.getOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber);

    if (order == null && isValidOrderNumber(orderNumber)) {
     log.warn("{} is a invalid order number", orderNumber);
     return;
    }
}
```

This is my test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InvoiceUpdateListenerTest {

  @Mock
  private OrderService orderService;
  @Mock
  Logger log;

  @InjectMocks
  private InvoiceUpdateListener invoiceUpdateListener;


@Test
  public void testReceiveInvoiceWhenvalidOrderNumberIsReceived() {
  
    var message = "s3://2020/08/12/5060001-5678.pdf";
    var orderNumber = "5060001";

    when(orderService.getOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber)).thenReturn(null);
    invoiceUpdateListener.receiveInvoice(message);
    verify(log, times(1)).warn("{} is a invalid order number", orderNumber);

  }
```

I have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.simplify4u</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I get this

```
Wanted but not invoked:
log.warn(
    "{} is a invalid order number",
    "5060001"
);
com.kfz24.order.invoice.InvoiceUpdateListenerTest.testReceiveInvoiceWhenValidOrderNumberIsReceived(InvoiceUpdateListenerTest.java:80)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: Where does `OrderService` get defined in `InvoiceUpdateListener`?

Comment: Ohh.. that is missed. It should be a dependency

Comment: It doesnt let me add now and complains that this question contains mostly code, please add some details

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Test
public void testReceiveInvoiceWhenvalidOrderNumberIsReceived() {
  
  var message = "s3://2020/08/12/5060001-5678.pdf";
  var orderNumber = "5060001";

  when(orderService.getOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber)).thenReturn(null);
    invoiceUpdateListener.receiveInvoice(message);
    verify(log, times(1)).warn("{} is a invalid order number", orderNumber);

}
```

your when will not be picked up because orderNumber != null. you've just set it to a non null value on the line above.

Comment: order is being checked for null, which is set by the when